# navigation controller doesn't show up iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an application with a tab bar as the root controller. I have four items in the tabbar. The second item is a table view and this should have a navigation controller of course, the thing is that i don't even get the navigation bar to show up and i have no idea how to do it. So i tried to guess after a long time in google without success. This is what i did in the viewDidLoad method:

```
SearchNavController *navController = [[SearchNavController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

    [searchNavController release];
```

With that i got an IlegalArgumentException.
How can i get the navigation bar to show up?

Thanks in advance guys

Have a nice day!

Comment: You have taken Uitabbarconrtoller progamatically or using Interface builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used interface builder to setup your tabbarcontroller. follow the following steps to get navigation bar and navigation controller in your tabbarcontroller:

Open Mainwindow.xib and select tababarcontroller .
In the attribute inspector , select the item1 in viewcontroller and from the arrows to the right change it to navigation controller.

Try this link:
[link 1](http://blog.willwinder.com/2011/05/xcode4-uitabbarcontroller-with.html)

Comment: that would have been easy if i was using Xcode 3, i recently updated to Xcode 4 and as i'm a beginner i'm having a lot of problems using interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Your `navController` should probably an ordinary UIViewController with the view you want to display. Also you need the following to actually display the navigationController:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

The navigation controller should now show up with your view as it's content.

Comment: do you mean that i have to change the superclass in navController to UIViewController instead of UINavigationController?

Comment: i did what you said but my table view disappeared. Do you have an Interface Builder option? i'm using Xcode 4 and i don't find how to change from View Controller to Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using interface builder. Then Add UINavigation controller in each tab bar then add your view controller in uinavigation conrtroller. If you have 4 tabs then you have to put 4 navigation controller.

UITabbarcontroller ->>Tab Bar >>
   UINavigationController >> set its class to your viewcontroller

Comment: right, i dont find the option where you change from View Controller to Navigation Controller to the tab bar items.